# Adding smarty values in a loop

Tags: loops, smarty

I need to add together all of the values in an array that I am looping through in smarty.

I have one value at 4 and one value at 1.

I am looping through:

```
{foreach from=$stuffs key=k item=stuff}
     {assign var='quantity' value=$stuff.amount}
{/foreach}
```

when I want to then use {$quantity} I need to then get 5. Right now I am only getting the value of the last thing in the loop. How can I get those values added together?

Comment: did you try something like {assign var='quantity' value=$stuff.amount + $quantity}

Comment: Yeah I actually just got it and it looks just like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{assign var="qty" value="$stuffs"}
{foreach from=$stuffs key=k item=stuff}
     {$qty++}
{/foreach}
```